# Factorization of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I was just asked to factor $x^3+1$. I came to $(x^2-x+1)(x+1)$ after a while, and I was wondering, whether there is a good method to quicky factor such of polynomials.

Comment: Look for a simple root $a$ of the polynomial and divide the initial polynomial by $x-a$.

Comment: There is no nice way to factor most cubics. But school assignment cubics usually have at least one rational root, which can be quickly located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any *odd* $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ , we get:

$$a^n+b^n=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2-...-ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$

Note that if $\,n\,$ is even the above does **not** work (the alternating signs in the right parentheses don't fix as one would expect!)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the rational root theorem and polynomial division.

This comes in very handy!

Answer (score 1):

You are usually asked to remember $x^3-a^3=(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)$ and $x^3+a^3=(x+a)(x^2-ax+a^2)$.  In general,
$$x^n-a^n=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+...+a^{n-2}x+a^{n-1})$$

If $$y=x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+...+a^{n-2}x+a^{n-1}$$
$$xy=x^n+ax^{n-1}+...+a^{n-2}x^2+a^{n-1}x$$
$$-ay=-ax^{n-1}-a^2x^{n-2}-...-a^{n-1}x-a^n$$

Add $xy$ and $-ay$ and all the terms will cancel out except for $x^n-a^n$, showing

$$xy-ay=(x-a)y=x^n-a^n$$

For your equation, $n=3$ and $a=-1$.